# sshj : permissions problems when downloading file

Tags: java, sftp, sshj

I am trying to download some files vis sftp using a java application which uses the sshj library. I  am using [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-file-sftp)

My code is as follows:

```
    try {
        sftpClient = client.newSFTPClient();
        remoteFileList = sftpClient.ls("gtdt/xml");
        logger.debug("trying to explicitly donwload file");
        sftpClient.get("remotepath/xml/somefile.xml", new FileSystemFile(localDownloadDir));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("Error getting list of remote files on sftp server", e);
        fail("error getting list or remote ftp files");
        
    }
```

Later I loop over the files that were returned:

```
    assertTrue(remoteFileList.size() > 0);
    for (RemoteResourceInfo info : remoteFileList) {
        logger.info(info.toString());
    }
```

but when I try to download any files (have tried one and many) like so

```
    // get first file in list and download
    RemoteResourceInfo info = remoteFileList.get(0);
    try {
        String localCopyPath = localDownloadDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + info.getName();
        FileSystemFile localCopyFile = new FileSystemFile(localDownloadDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + info.getName());
        logger.debug("attempting to copy remote file " + info.getPath() + " to : " + localCopyPath);
        sftpClient.get("remotepath/xml/somefile.xml", localCopyFile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("unable to copy file to local dir ", e);
        fail("unable to copy " + info.getName() + " to local dir " + localDownloadDir.getAbsolutePath());
    }
```

I get an error like this:

```
[main] WARN net.schmizz.sshj.xfer.FileSystemFile - Could not set permissions for c:\mypath\somefile.xml to 1a0
```

any idea how to fix this? The actual code that is being executed there starts at line 142 [here.](https://github.com/hierynomus/sshj/blob/master/src/main/java/net/schmizz/sshj/xfer/FileSystemFile.java) It wasn't clear to me if this is and issue on my local machine or something I need to configure in sshj.

thanks!

Comment: Does the file(s) get downloaded or not? If yes, then ignore the warning, because the permission being set are for Linux/Unix OS (permissions mask for Read Write and Execute) and Windows does not have them.

Comment: ok weird...the file did download, but it wasn't before. thanks!